# Normals probably not consistent after CGAL 3D Surface Mesh Generation

Tags: opengl, cgal

I use the package from CGAL, 3D Surface Mesh Generation.

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/index.html#Chapter_3D_Surface_Mesh_Generation

I started from the example code:

http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example.html

and now tried to extract the relevant facets (=triangles) to display from the variable c2t3 of type C2t3. A good explanation how to do that was in

http://wiki.schmid.dk/wiki/index.php/CGAL

I followed this explanation with a little modification, that I found in

http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/normal-vector-of-a-facet-td1580004.html

Now when I give the triangles to OpenGL by the code-snippet below, the displayed surface is a mosaic of yellow (my lighting color) and black triangles - I conclude this is because the surface normals are not consistent. But how can that be? If one follows the argument in the last link above it should come out right. Could anyone with better acquaintance with CGAL and the 3D Surface Mesh Generation and its data structures give me some guidance? (I also tried several obvious alternatives to the code below, but nothing worked correctly).

```
for (C2t3::Facet_iterator fit = c2t3.facets_begin(); fit != c2t3.facets_end(); ++fit) {

        const Point_3& p0 = fit->first->vertex((fit->second))->point();
        // points on the facet
        const Point_3& p1 = fit->first->vertex((fit->second+1)&3)->point();
        const Point_3& p2 = fit->first->vertex((fit->second+2)&3)->point();
        const Point_3& p3 = fit->first->vertex((fit->second+3)&3)->point();

        Vector_3 n = ( fit->second % 2 == 1) ?
                           CGAL::normal(p1, p2, p3) :
                           CGAL::normal(p1, p3, p2);

        n = n /sqrt(n * n);

        glNormal3d(n.x(), n.y(), n.z());
        glVertex3d(p1.x(), p1.y(), p1.z());
        glVertex3d(p2.x(), p2.y(), p2.z());
        glVertex3d(p3.x(), p3.y(), p3.z());

        ++cnt2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you extract facets is correct and will provide you a consistent orientation of the facets is you consider them from the same "side" of the surface. For example, consider a sphere embedded in a c2t3. If you only consider facets using tetrahedron inside the sphere then your function will do what you want. But since the iteration over facets does not guarantee you will not have tetrahedron outside the sphere your function will display incorrectly oriented facets.
A simple solution is to use the function [`CGAL::output_surface_facets_to_polyhedron`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/group__PkgSurfaceMesher3FunctionsIO.html#gab2fbf4e1a4cf30fa19304138461623e7) to first create a polyhedron out of the c2t3 and use it for display.
Alternatively you can also look at the implementation which is not that complicated and mimic what is done.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. As a provisional solution I had implemented the following: I check if for a given vertex v and "pre-normal" n (calculated by cross product in the facet f the vertex v belongs to) the point v + eps * n is in the negative range of the triangulated implicit function 'sphere_function' and if yes replaced n by -n. In the special cases I used for testing, this worked, but the solution you proposed is of course safer and better. I am just a bit reluctant to change the code from the C2t3 way to the Polyhedron_3 way.